# Hiding elements having non-unique attributes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some elements in a long list. What I want to do is search for elements which have a non-unique attribute value in the attribute `data-title`, and hide all of the excessive elements, so that only 1 remains.

Consider the following list:

```
<div data-title="big hero 6">title</div>
<div data-title="big hero 6">title</div>
<div data-title="american sniper">title</div>
<div data-title="big hero 6">title</div>
<div data-title="some movie about cats">title</div>
```

Since there are 3 elements having the same attribute value "`big hero 6`", I want to hide the first 2, so that only the last one remains out of these.

How can I achieve this?

The result would look similar to this in the raw HTML after jQuery hides them:

```
<div data-title="big hero 6" style="display:none;">title</div>
<div data-title="big hero 6" style="display:none;">title</div>
<div data-title="american sniper">title</div>
<div data-title="big hero 6">title</div>
<div data-title="some movie about cats">title</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through all the elements with a `data-title` attribute.

Grab the title of each element and then check to see if the succeeding sibling elements have the same `data-title` attribute value using `.nextAll('[data-title="' + title + '"]')`.

If any other succeeding sibling elements have the same value, hide the element.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv8m8L9y/)

```
$('[data-title]').each(function () {
    var title = $(this).data('title'),
        occurrences = $(this).nextAll('[data-title="' + title + '"]').length;

    if (occurrences) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: nextAll was all i needed! did not know about it. thanks a lot man! :)